# How can I get an img to work like a button and rotate when clicked and rotate again when clicked again in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get an custom image button to work like an on off button in Javascript?

Here is some of my code:

```
f.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e) {
        o.setAttribute('style', 'transform:rotate(45deg)')
    }
    if (e == false) {
        o.setAttribute('style', 'transform:rotate(0deg)')
    }
}
```

The first part of it works (rotate to 45 degrees) but the second part is what I am having trouble with... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a boolean to track the current state of the element or check the element's current style, but it is simpler to toggle a class.

```js
const f = document.querySelector('img');
f.addEventListener('click', e => f.classList.toggle('rotated'));
```

```css
.rotated {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"/> Click this image (wait for it to load)
```

Comment: Awesome! That totally does the job..thanks dude!

Comment: Let me ask this properly, is there now a way to action this ```d.setAttribute('style', 'display:block')``` when triggering the button, and this ```d.setAttribute('style', 'display:none')``` when triggering it again?

Comment: @user1924813 You could have a class called hide that applies `display: none` which is present on the element at the start. Then use d.classList.toggle('hide')

Comment: Its a good idea, and worked when the button is pressed once (goes to ```display:block``` ).But when pressed again the ```display:none``` doesn't come into effect.